# Play Youtube video width LibVLCSharp + xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, libvlcsharp

I using libCLCSharp and xamarin forms to playvideo. 
With  this url below is OK. but when i replace by an youtuble video it can not to play.
how can i do it. Thanks

my code:

_libvlc = new LibVLC();

var media = new Media(_libvlc, "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4", FromType.FromLocation);
myVideo.MediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media) { EnableHardwareDecoding = true };
myVideo.MediaPlayer.Play();

Comment: Youtube video URLs are for the Youtube wrapper, not the embedded video itself.  It is a TOS violation to bypass that, you should review the "YouTube
Data API" https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/

Comment: @duongvan it is a violation of the terms of service (and potentially the reason why this doesnt work) to play YouTube videos in anything but the youtube player, please take a look:https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

Answer (score 3):

Docs: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp/-/blob/3.x/docs/how_do_I_do_X.md#how-do-i-play-a-youtube-video

```cs
Core.Initialize();

using(var libVLC = new LibVLC())
{
    var media = new Media(libVLC, "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ", FromType.FromLocation);
    await media.Parse(MediaParseOptions.ParseNetwork);
    using (var mp = new MediaPlayer(media.SubItems.First()))
    {
            mp.Play();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can it happen that the Parse return no subitem now from youtube ? To test I used the sample ForegroundBackground that you did (good job btw! :) and I added that code to parse. My debugger result; https://imgur.com/a/I3iKD7K I ask as I tried with the VLC player directly (3.0.8) too, and I can't play it too.

Comment: if it doesn't work in VLC, it won't in libvlcsharp. What's the URL?

Comment: I tried the same song as in your exemple, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ. I tried in http too just in case, same result

Comment: this is a VLC issue. Will be fixed in the next VLC minor release